# How to transform a `typeorm` model into graphql payload?

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, typeorm, typegraphql

I am working on a microservice application. I have one Node.js service that acts as the 'data service' and runs `nestjs` with `typeorm` and `type-graphql` models. The data service uses the https://github.com/nestjs/graphql module to enable a graphql interface and playground.

I have a second service that is a 'websocket service' that clients subscribe too.

The 'data service' sends HTTP requests to the 'websocket service' using the `axios` library these request then get sent over websocket to the clients. The messages being sent from the 'data service' to the 'socket service' include `typeorm` models. When sent through axios `typeorm` models get passed through `JSON.stringify`. Herein lines the problem. This `stringify` transform is including  fields that should not be in the final output and also missing graphql schema metadata.

Instead of stringifying the models I would like to convert them to a graphql payload similiar to what the graphql playground returns. From what I can tell this graphql transformation is deeply abstracted away and happens some where within the `nest/graphql` module which abstracts the `apollo/server` module.

This is a complicated system and hard to extract isolated code examples from it. Leave comment if anything needs to be clarified. The following is some example in the 'data service', we have a `Profile` entity that has `profile.entity.ts` `profile.service.ts` and `profile.resolver.ts`

The `Profile` entity looks like

```js
import { Field, Int, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql'
import { Column, Entity, ManyToOne, OneToMany } from 'typeorm'
import { BaseEntity } from '../common/base/base.entity'


@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Profile extends BaseEntity {
  @Field()
  @Column({ unique: true })
  public username: string

  @Field()
  @Column()
  public name: string

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public birthday?: Date

  // Relations

  @Column()
  public accountId: string

  @ManyToOne(type => Account, account => account.profiles, { eager: true })
  public account: Account

  }
```

The `Profile` reference is retrieved and sent to the socket service like

```
    const profileReference = await this.profileService.fetchById(profileId)
    await this.socketService.sendHomeEvent(profileReference)
```

Here is where we would like to take the `profileReference` and serialize it to a graphql response payload. The `JSON.stringify` result on `profileReference` includes fields specifically the `Account` field which should not be included.

Comment: If the "data service" is running nest.js, does that mean you're exposing a client-facing API through it in addition to the "websocket service" Is the "websocket service" also a GraphQL service (presumably just using subscriptions)?

Comment: @DanielRearden yes the nestjs 'data service' does have a client-facing graphql API and also has a graphql apollo playground. The "websocket service" does not have any GraphQL infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

Given a GraphQL schema, you can execute any arbitrary query server-side. `type-graphql` exposes a `buildSchema` for building your schema from your resolver classes as shown [here](https://typegraphql.ml/docs/bootstrap.html#create-executable-schema).

```
import { buildSchema } from 'type-graphql'
import { graphql } from 'graphql'

const schema = await buildSchema({
  resolvers: [ProfileResolver],
})
const query = `
  # your query here
`
const root = {}
const context = {...}
const variables = {...}
const { data, errors } = await graphql(schema, query, root, context, variables)
```

Unfortunately, I don't *think* nest.js exposes the schema it builds under the hood, so you'd have to do that yourself.

Comment: unfortunately on further look this does not accurately answer the question. This answer is suggesting a separate graphql query and not using the reference to the `typeorm` reference that is already available.

Comment: The fact that you're using `typeorm` is irrelevant with regard to your schema. I'm not sure what you're expecting here. The decorators you use only inform `type-graphql` how to generate a schema from the classes you provide. There's no utility function for turning a model instance into a "GraphQL payload" beyond actually returning the instance as part of a query. The coercion of your class instance into the response you see happens *through* GraphQL execution.

Comment: in my example I have reference to a `typeorm` object; `profileReference` that is queried from Postgres. This reference gets passed through the `nestjs` middleware and `apollo-server` and is converted to a graphql response. I want to recreate that. This answer exhibits doing an entirely separate and redundant query

Comment: Redundant, yes, but unfortunately that's the only way to do what you're asking for given your current architecture. The "converted to a GraphQL response" part only happens when the query is executed against the schema.

Comment: If the only reason you're trying to get a GraphQL response is because serializing the instance is exposing properties on the instance you don't want to expose, as you've indicated in an earlier question, then you should utilize a custom method for serializing like I suggested before.

Comment: I'm also looking for meta data like the graphql type annotations that are will not be available or will have to be reproduced in custom serialization method